# Unable to enter date time value returned by PayPal IPN into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, paypal-ipn

Paypal IPN is returning a $_POST payload which among other things, consists of a datetime item named `payment_date`. The value of this variable is in the following format:

```
23%3A54%3A48+Jul+23%2C+2016+PDT
```

This is of course, urlencoded. I am processing it for a db update as follows:

```
$payment_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', urldecode($_POST['payment_date']) );
```

This final `$payment_date` variable is what I'm later attempting to insert into my table using PDO. However, the above process is returning an error:

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered in /purchases/paypal_ipn.php on line 70
```

Despite the error, the insert is still working but the date being entered is incorrect:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

Before this, I had tried just the urldecode without any formatting:

```
$payment_date = urldecode($_POST['payment_date']) );
```

This one allowed the db insert without any error but the value entered was still incorrect:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the decoded timestamp from PayPal looks like:

```
23:54:48 Jul 23, 2016 PDT
```

This is not in a format which is standard to MySQL, but you can convert it using a combination of `STR_TO_DATE` and `CONVERT_TZ`:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(col, 1, 21), '%H:%i:%s %b %d, %Y'),
                  SUBSTRING(col, 23),      -- convert from PDT
                  '+00:00')                -- convert to UTC time
```

This answer does two things.  First, the call to `STR_TO_DATE` converts the PayPal timestamp into a legitimate MySQL datetime.  If you don't care about timezone, you can stop here.  If you do care about time zone, then you can also call `CONVERT_TZ` on the timestamp to convert it from California daylight saving time to UTC time.

Comment: Is there no way to do this in PHP, i.e. using a PHP function/algorithm instead of disturbing the SQL query? What if I remove the timezone portion from the value using one of the PHP string manipulation functions before passing it to the query?

Comment: You can directly insert a string of the form `YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-SS` into MySQL from PHP, but this will require that you build a string in this format.  The nice thing about `STR_TO_DATE` is that it takes care of this for you.